# How to select without arrow keys in INTELLIJ

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

[image: Auto-complete example]

I hate to use arrow keys in IntelliJ. However, when IntelliJ gives me some advices (auto complete, etc.), as in the picture, it seems that I have to choose them with mouse or arrow keys.

Is there a way that I can switch the selections without using arrow keys? 
For example, maybe I can use `<C-n>` (or other keys, like) to switch between these suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can go to Settings | Keymap, find actions "Up" and "Down" there and assign whatever shortcuts you like to them.

Comment: Thanks. In Mac OS, I added Control-b and Control-u to operation "Down" and "Up". In Windows, I haven't found good keymapings yet.

Comment: For me, Control-p and Control-n were preset in keymaps. (Mac, 2016)

Comment: they aren't in Intelij Idea classic